# How to Make column Duplicate Values to Unique?

Tags: python, pandas

df:

```
 colA   ColB   ColC
0  A      B      345
1  B      C      876
2  D      B      983
3  A      B      371
4  G      B      972
5  H      K      193
6  G      B      367
7  D      J      293


   colA  ColB   ColC
0  A_A    B      345
1  B      C      876
2  D      B      983
3  A_B    B      371
4  G_A    B      972
5  H      K      193
6  G_B    B      367
7  D      J      293
```

How to make Column Values unique if it is duplicates, For Example if you see I am checking ColA and ColB, if find any duplicates pair and I am appending _A to first one and _B to second one in ColA. If there are 3 pairs of  duplicates then it will Append the _C to to the third Pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is maximal `26` duplicated values like alphabets create dictionary by `enumerate` with `string.ascii_uppercase`, select only duplicated rows by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and add new values created by counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
import string

d = dict(enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase))

print (len(d))
26

m = df.duplicated(['colA', 'ColB'], keep=False)
df.loc[m, 'colA'] += '_' + df[m].groupby(['colA', 'ColB']).cumcount().map(d)
print (df)
  colA ColB  ColC
0  A_A    B   345
1    B    C   876
2    D    B   983
3  A_B    B   371
4  G_A    B   972
5    H    K   193
6  G_B    B   367
7    D    J   293
```

If possible add numbers instead alphabets is possible solution simplify:

```
m = df.duplicated(['colA', 'ColB'], keep=False)
df.loc[m, 'colA'] += '_' + df[m].groupby(['colA', 'ColB']).cumcount().astype(str)
print (df)
  colA ColB  ColC
0  A_0    B   345
1    B    C   876
2    D    B   983
3  A_1    B   371
4  G_0    B   972
5    H    K   193
6  G_1    B   367
7    D    J   293
```

Comment: what does += do ?

Comment: @harry - It is for join, here working same like `df.loc[m, 'colA'] =df.loc[m, 'colA'] + '_' + df[m].groupby(['colA', 'ColB']).cumcount().astype(str)`